# What is a software for logic and rules management?

Tags: windows, database, microsoft-excel, business-intelligence

I have developed an app that imports excel tables in a specific format and performs analysis on the data. I need to find a software that can

1. Take other excel/csv files and implement database logic to create the excel table in the required table form that my app uses.
2. (Optional) Connect to other databases to grab and join specified tables into a excel table that my app can read.

What (not too expensive) possible software can I use to do this?

Comment: How much it's not too expensive?, a price bracket might be helpful to narrow your possibilities.